# How do I filter all URLs with a certain extension to be listed in a WeChat social network in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, wechat

So I 've discovered that all visits to my website by users who are using the Chinese social network, WeChat, have extra parameters after the landing page URL.

For example, most people who visit the page have this listed as the landing page URL:
`/blog/zhou-youguang-the-father-of-pinyin/`

However, anyone who visited from the WeChat Moments feature, has this listed as the landing page URL: `/blog/zhou-youguang-the-father-of-pinyin/?from=timeline&isappinstalled=0`

So it adds `?from=timeline&isappinstalled=0` to the end of the URL.

There are other extensions that WeChat may add to the end of the URL including:

- /?from=timeline
- /?from=groupmessage&isappinstalled=0
- /?from=singlemessage&isappinstalled=0

Further in the "Acquisition Overview" section, it lists these visits, not under "Social", but instead under "Direct".

I want to use the filters feature in Google Analytics to put all of these visitors in the Social section and categorized with the social network WeChat.

Is this possible? How do I do this.

Thanks!

Update: I've written an article about [“?from=timeline&isappinstalled=0” on Google Analytics](http://ivannovation.com/blog/fromtimelineisappinstalled0-on-google-analytics/). I've just explained what caused it, but I haven't been able to figure out how to organize these visitors with Google Analytics effectively. I'm still researching this. If you have any ideas for me to try, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the Channel Settings.

Go to Admin > View (the right column) > Channel Setting > Channel Grouping.

Take the "Default Channel Grouping" and take "Social". Here you can add the destination URLs from WeChat to the social channel grouping - like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks. I'm trying that. It doesn't seem to change historical data. Perhaps it will only change the way future visitors are displayed. I'll watch it.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy, just add two [advanced filters](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034823?hl=en&authuser=0) in GA:

1) [WeChat Campaign Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvkC9.png) fliter:

Request URI = "from=([^&]*)&isappinstalled=(0|1)"

Selete Campaign Source as Output, and set value to "WeChat"

2) [WeChat Campaign Medium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvXuD.png) filter:

Request URI = "from=([^&]*)"

Select Campaign Medium as Output, and set value to "$A1"

Done, You can see it in [action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucSJN.png)